# Google plist issue in Xcode 12 and Swift 5.3

Tags: swift, firebase

I am using firebase for developing my app with Google Plist. While running I am getting below error, trying to add again and again but it's still getting error. Could anyone help me on this issue?

**Error**

Thread 1: "`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project.

Comment: Are you sure it has the correct name and is added to the correct target?

Comment: This very likely means that you missed a step in Google's instructions on how to download and install that file.

Comment: Yes sir I have added to my target file in xcode project

Comment: But I followed and added that file in my project and i ran it still it showing same error

Comment: Are you sure it's named "GoogleService-Info.plist"?

Comment: GoogleService-Info (1).plist same i got it from firebase download

Comment: I have changed the name with GoogleService-Info.plist now it is working now thank you so. much for help and immediate response

Answer (score 0):

As we discovered in the comment thread above, your `plist` file was named incorrectly. It needs to be named `"GoogleService-Info.plist"`.

If you have downloaded this file or other Firebase `plist` files in the past, the names may have something appended to avoid collisions like `"GoogleService-Info (1).plist"`, which needs to be renamed for the Firebase SDK to recognize it.

Comment: If this answered your question (which we know it did, from the comment thread), you can mark the answer as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark.